# Can I play Minecraft Bedrock on Xbox if I got it on mobile?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can I play Minecraft Bedrock on Xbox if I bought it on mobile? Do I need to log into the account I bought it on or do I need to purchase again? I really want to play Minecraft again but on Xbox.
I tried to log into my account; I'm logged in on mobile.

Comment: Requesting off-site solutions is not really acceptable here. We want to build a resource where future visitors with the same question can easily find the answer on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. You are not paying for the account but the game itself. You can log into the same account but the game will still cost money.

Answer (score 0):

you can still play Minecraft bedrock with a Xbox controller on Mobile, but the purchase is different so you will have to buy it again on Xbox. Unless you use Xbox Gamepass then you can play on both.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that you have to still pay for it but I'm not to sure as I play on pc, I'm sure you still have to pay unless you had xbox 1 edition and you get offered it for free or you did
-Hope this helps